# How do I render a list on API response in vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am new to vue and trying to render a list of items from an API response

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
// This starter template is using Vue 3 <script setup> SFCs
// Check out https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#sfc-script-setup
import ServiceCard from './components/ServiceCard.vue'
import { parse, stringify } from 'yaml'
import { onMounted, onUpdated } from 'vue'
import Vue from 'vue'

interface ServiceAPIResponse { host: string, protocol: string, services: [{ subdomain: string, apikey: string }] };

let yaml: ServiceAPIResponse;

onMounted(() => {
  fetch('https://api.my.domain/').then((resp) => {
    resp.json().then((data: ServiceAPIResponse) => {
      yaml = data;
      console.log(yaml);
    });
  });
});

onUpdated(() => {
  console.log('onupdated');
});

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
    <ul v-if="yaml">
      <li v-for="service in yaml.services" :key="service.subdomain">
        <ServiceCard :name="service.subdomain" :host="yaml.host" :subdomain="service.subdomain" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Coming from react, I would expect a re-render to occur when I update the value of `yaml`. I have tried wrapping it with `reactive()` but I don't understand vue well enough.
I don't understand why my `v-if` remains falsy after I set `yaml`'s value.

Is `v-if` even the right way to handle this?

With this code, I get the error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'services')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be reactive a variable must be wrapped in a ref (or reactive (the difference is not important for you for now)),

in your case, init your variable with an empty object

```
import { Ref, ref } from 'vue'    
let yaml: Ref<ServiceAPIResponse> = ref({})
```

then when you want to assign new values

```
yaml.value = data;
```